# Laravel Eager Loading is Null with Polymorphic Relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my model I have:

```
//UserAddress.php

protected $with = ['address'];

public function address()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Address', 'addressable');
}

//User.php
public function userAddress()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserAddress::class);
}

//Address.php
public function addressable() 
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

But when I call `dd(auth()->user()->userAddress))` The address realtionship is not loaded. It is still null.

```
#attributes: array:4 [
    "id" => "1"
    "user_id" => "1"
    "created_at" => "2018-11-13 10:11:54"
    "updated_at" => "2018-11-13 10:11:54"
  ]
  #original: array:4 [
    "id" => "1"
    "user_id" => "1"
    "created_at" => "2018-11-13 10:11:54"
    "updated_at" => "2018-11-13 10:11:54"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [
    "address" => null
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
```

However, with `dd(auth()->user()->userAddress()->get()))` the relationship is eager loaded.

What is the problem?

**Edit**

It is super weird. If I write `auth()->user()->userAddress->address` I get null (it should not be that). And when I remove `protected $with = ['address'];` `auth()->user()->userAddress->address` gets me the correct model.

Comment: Please put `\DB::enableQueryLog();` in `AppServiceProvider::boot();` and 
`dd(\DB::getQueryLog());` in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar issue. It is loading the related models, but under different key.

I got a pivot model called `Skillable` it has a `morphTo` relationship to get the related morphed model.

```php
public function morphedModel(): MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo('skillable');
}
```

That works fine without eager loading when used like that

```php
echo $skillable->morphedModel->id; // return some id
```

However when using eager loading, the `morphedModel` prop is null.

```php
Skillable::with('morphedModel')->get()->first()->morhphedModel; // returns null
```

Turns out the eager loading is working almost as expected, however the related (morphed) models are loaded under `skillable` relationship instead.

```php
dump(Skillable::with('morphedModel')->get()->first());
```

returns

```
...

#relations: array:2 [▶
        "morphedModel" => null
        "skillable" => App\Models\Lesson {#2376 ▶
```

Not sure why though.. something with my relation definition I guess.

Comment: Just solved my own problem by redefining the relationship like so: `$this->morphTo('morphedModel', 'skillable_type', 'skillable_id', 'id');`

Comment: great job @repair

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a one-to-one relationship where the id field was a string. Everything worked until I eager-loaded the connecting table (user_address in you case).

In my case I'd forgotten to define `public $incrementing = false;` in the connecting table, and once I had added this everything worked.